# Suddenly Hard disk performance deteriorated

Tags: hard-drive, performance

Everything was fine till yesterday. From today morning I've been observing that videos (on my harddisk using kmplayer) aren't playing smoothly.

I suspected that it might be the player problem, so tried playing using other VLC & other players but same problem observed.

I then, suspected that it might be because players are unable to read at the rate required. I used *Process Hacker* to see the rate at which the process *kmplayer.exe* is doing IO operations.
[image]
This rate is hardly going above 80kB/s and by video is getting struck everytime this rate is dropping below 60KB/s.

To confirm I copied the same file to another external Hard disk and when played the same file. File played seamlessly and the IO rate was around 150KB/s and some times even reached a max of 900KB/s.

Suspecting problem with the hard drive. I've used *HD Tune* to do some Benchmark testing and to my surprise `max speed is 3.3MB/s and average is 3.2MB/s`. This was not the case earlier. The speed of copying a file from this disk to another used to be easily more than 10MB/s (I don't remember exact figure).

[image]

*HD Tune* Status report of this disk had one row marked `Attention`

```
Status    ID                              Current  Worst    Threshold Value    Description     
Attention (C7) Interface CRC Error Count  200      200      0         14165    Number of interface communication errors: 14165
```

I don't know if that is relevant or not.

One more thing is that this disk is 99% full, with 6 partitions made on it. Excepting a single partition on all other partitions the `fragmentation level is less than 10%`.

I'm using Western Digital 3.5-inch 1 TB WD Black disk. whose [specifications](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=760) are as follows:

```
WD Black 1 TB SATA Hard Drives ( WD1002FAEX)

Product Specifications  
    Interface   SATA 6 Gb/s


Performance Specifications  
    Rotational Speed    7,200 RPM (nominal)
    Buffer Size 64 MB
    Average Latency 4.20 ms (nominal)
    Load/unload Cycles  300,000 minimum

Transfer Rates
    Transfer Rate (Buffer To Disk)  126 MB/s (Max)


Physical Specifications 
    Formatted Capacity  1,000,204 MB
    Capacity    1 TB
    Form Factor 3.5 Inch
    User Sectors Per Drive  1,953,525,169
```

**Question:**

What exactly is the problem? How to rectify it?

Comment: You don't the HDD is failing error correction.  So its reading data, encountering an error, and unable to correct the error.

Comment: @Ramhound: OK! what kind of error? What can be done?

Comment: **Nothing can be done.**  Already explained the error. You need to replace the hdd.

Comment: You mean error in the data? or error while communicating with motherboard? I mean should I get a new motherboard or return this HDD, its still under warranty. More importantly, is this error responsible for reduction in the speed?

Comment: Please read my first comment.  Your HDD is attempting to perform error correction ( normal ) but its failing to do so ( a problem ) the solution to that problem is to replace the HDD.  Your speed is impacted because your HDD keeps trying to perform error correction on the data it reads.  Why bring the motherboard up when I clearly indicate you need to replace the HDD?

Comment: Sorry! I somehow missed reading "You need to replace the HDD". Is it just because of faulty hardware or because of my misuse. I want to know so that I can be cautious with my next drive.

Comment: All HDDS will fail in time. You may not have done anything wrong.

Comment: Unless you shook your computer while it was def ragging you can't damage your under normal conditions.